# How to serve static profile images in node

Tags: image, node.js, express, user-profile

This is really more of a "using what method" than a "how-to" question. I am creating a site in NodeJS with Express. So, each user has the ability to upload a `profile picture`, and my concern is how to route requests for these images. A couple of questions I have are:

- Can I use express.static() to serve a default file if a valid one isn't specified? If not, am I going to have to specify a `GET` route for `/img/profile`and handle the FS querying there?
- How can I find the correct image if multiple file extensions are allowed? (I originally just removed the file extension and they appeared in img tags anyway, is that okay?)
- I am currently naming all pictures after their user's name. Looking ahead into the future (for apps I may have to scale), what are normal naming conventions for static user content? Are most stored with a UUID referencing the content in the database?
- What else should I take into consideration that I may not have accounted for yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## First question:

At present, I'd recommend storing your images in a predictable location that can be inferred from some combination of columns or fields in your database entries.  One of those fields or columns would be a filename (accounts for different extensions).  Then, if they haven't uploaded an image, you just lay down in your view code a reference to the generic "has not set an image" file.

`express.static` obviously *can* server static files, but it *currently* doesn't have a way to serve some other file if the one you wanted isn't there.  Because this sounded like fun, I made some modifications to `static` to support what you request and submitted a couple of pull requests (the feature touched 2 different modules):

- In `send`: https://github.com/visionmedia/send/pull/33
- In `connect`: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/pull/999

I don't know if those will get included in the project, but if you want to see my forks that have these changes, they are here:

- https://github.com/bigohstudios/send
- https://github.com/bigohstudios/connect

If this went through, you would mount a static at the root of your profile image files:

`app.use(static('<profile image files root>', { fallback: 'anon.jpg'}))`

## Second question

I generally store the extension in my DB, then when I load the image, I have the correct extension to put into the `src` attribute on the `img` tag.

## Third question

If you can guarantee unique names, then using those would work.  I prefer using the DB id or a UUID as you suggest.  It's less intuitive when scanning all the image uploads, but I rarely find myself doing that.  I'm usually hunting for a specific image, and I can look up the identifier for that as needed.

## Fourth question

You may end up storing the static content outside your app server (e.g. on S3).  If that happens, then of course `static` won't help you.

Comment: I already feel closer to the right path. Thanks for the awesome info!

Comment: Glad it helps.  And FWIW, the project maintainers didn't agree with my approach and rejected the PRs.  :)  They're smart people, so it's probably worth considering their comments.  Happy coding!